# How much entropy exists in knowing the specific sorting of a list of $n$ many items with repetition in the list?

Tags: entropy

If I have a bag of $b$ many balls, each numbered from $1, 2, \ldots, b$, and I uniformly-randomly pick one ball.  Then I ask you *"how much information would you gain should I tell you the ball which I have selected?"*.  Your answer will be $\log_2(b)$.  This is just Shannon's entropy of picking one ball at uniform-random.

Now, imagine that I repeated the same ball picking from the $b$-balls bag, uniformly-randomly, with replacement, and took $n$ many balls, and formed a list.  The list has $n$ many balls, possibly with repetition.  ***My question is:***  what is the entropy of this $n$-balls list?

---

***What I did so far:*** I think the total space of possibilities is $b^n$, so $n\log_2(b)$?

Or is the space $nb$, hence $\log(nb)$?

After all, the size of this  list is just $n$ many balls!  Or, is it just $\log_2(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it is clear that each of the $n$ uniform selections from $b$ balls are independent. So the overall entropy is $n$ times the entropy of picking one ball uniformly, or $n \log b.$

For any two random variables, $X,Y$ which are independent, their joint entropy is given by $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y).$

For you the $i^{th}$ random variable is $X_i$ with entropy $\log b$ and you apply the above by induction and get
$$
H(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=H(X_1)+\cdots+H(X_n)=n H(X_1)=n \log b.
$$